# How to make carousel with images?

Tags: javascript, arrays, carousel

For a larger project in a web design class, I have to create a carousel that moves between images every ten seconds.

We did an example in class that worked with changing between 10 different words, but I can't seem to add in the pictures and have it work.

I was just wondering if someone could help me out with this part of the assignment I can't seem to grasp.

Here's what I have so far:

```html
<head>
  <title>JS Examples: Arrays</title>
  <script>
    function showImages(id) {
      var images = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5', 'img6', 'img7', 'img8', 'img9', 'img10'];
      document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = images[id];
      console.log('Position:' + id + ' image:' + images[id]);
      if (id < images.length - 1) {
        id = id + 1;
      } else {
        id = 0;
      }
      setTimeout(showImages, 10000, id);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="showImages(0)">
  <article>
    <p id="image">Showing Images</p>
  </article>
</body>
```

Comment: Unless you want to keep getting `document.getElementById('image')`, assign it outside your `showImages` function like `const imgElement = document.getElementById('image') ` then inside `showImages`, `imgElement.src = images[id]+'.png'`. Of course. you may need to change that extension. But really, if they are based on a number just increment that instead... just concatenate.

Comment: First, you'll need an `<img>` tag on your page. Second, instead of (or in addition to) changing the `.innerHTML` property of `<p id="image">`, you'll need to change the `.src` property of the `<img>` tag. E.g. `document.getElementById('foo').src=images[id]+'.jpg'`;